# Multiline editable text and image in a scrollview filling all space

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, scrollview, fillviewport

I'm trying to achieve on **iOS** something that is very easy to do on Android, which is to have a normal constrained screen but that if at some point the view is taller than the screen, then it behaves as a scrollView:

**This is what I want but on iOS:**

(the android implementation is just using a ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView with `fillViewport="true"`)

1. This is how it looks normally. The bottom view is constrained at the bottom and the EditText  (On iOS I would use a UITextView because I need a multiline editable text) at the top.
   [image]
2. When the text field grows it just expands vertically.
   [image]
3. You can scroll normally too.
   [image]

I tried a lot of things on iOS, constraining the views to the content layout guide and/or to the frame layout guide but nothing works exactly as this. There is always a strange behavior or it doesn't even scroll...

Comment: Disable scrolling for your text view. If you have your text view (and other UI elements) embedded in a scroll view, and your constraints are set properly, scrolling of the scroll view is fully automatic.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard to layout your views? Or doing it all through code?

Comment: I'm already disabling the uitextview scroll. I mainly tried to do it in the storyboard but still get weird results. If you have a working example similar to what I said you can attach screenshots/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If scrolling is disabled on a `UITextView`, its height will auto-adjust to the height of the content -- even while typing into it.

With constraints set properly, the scroll view holding the text view will automatically enable / disable scrolling based on the embedded subviews overall height.

Here's how it looks in Storyboard / Interface Builder:

[image]

- the `.systemTeal` view is the scroll view.
- the yellow background view is the text view.
- the green background view is just some other view.

Scroll view is constrained Top / Leading / Trailing at 20-points, with a Height of 288.

Text view and Some view are constrained to the scroll view's Content Layout Guide, with 12-pts "padding."

Here's how it looks at run-time:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is the source to the Storyboard so you can inspect it and try it out (no ViewController code needed). Just create a new project, right-click on the default Main.storyboard, select `Open As -> Source Code`, replace the entire xml source with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="End-pl-wnP">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="GaN-aS-ajy">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="End-pl-wnP" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8Qt-g9-qT2">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eZS-Cx-qYs" userLabel="TealScrollView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="335" height="288"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" scrollEnabled="NO" text="This is the text view." textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7Se-XO-OPS" userLabel="YellowTextView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="12" width="311" height="45"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                        <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                    </textView>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Some View" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2Mx-yX-VZg" userLabel="GreenSomeView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="47.5" y="77" width="240" height="60"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45009386540000001" green="0.98132258650000004" blue="0.4743030667" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="240" id="AqV-is-i0i"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="fff-dn-2i5"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="30"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemTealColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2Mx-yX-VZg" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="7Se-XO-OPS" secondAttribute="centerX" id="45Q-oe-nAR"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2Mx-yX-VZg" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="eBA-LY-1GE" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-12" id="4NU-Uv-m9I"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="7Se-XO-OPS" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="eBA-LY-1GE" secondAttribute="leading" constant="12" id="BYn-bQ-6KV"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2Mx-yX-VZg" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="7Se-XO-OPS" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="Hzr-4N-5Ql"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="288" id="U0g-vv-Ze5"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="7Se-XO-OPS" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="QZA-CN-WnC" secondAttribute="width" constant="-24" id="VPa-39-0aV"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="7Se-XO-OPS" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="eBA-LY-1GE" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="12" id="ZVh-Fb-ig9"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="7Se-XO-OPS" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="eBA-LY-1GE" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="kWx-ff-DeQ"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="eBA-LY-1GE"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="QZA-CN-WnC"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="NOq-jz-yuG"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="eZS-Cx-qYs" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="NOq-jz-yuG" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="Oh5-z6-HeB"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="eZS-Cx-qYs" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="NOq-jz-yuG" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="ZeN-Gb-OvE"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NOq-jz-yuG" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="eZS-Cx-qYs" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="bxt-As-NfZ"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="waK-s5-f38" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="341" y="155"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="labelColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemTealColor">
            <color red="0.35294117647058826" green="0.78431372549019607" blue="0.98039215686274506" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

---

**Edit** - *after comments...*

If you want the "other view" to stick to the bottom *until it needs to scroll*:

- embed the text view and other view(s) in a "holder" view
- constrain that holder view to the Content Layout Guide
- constrain "some view" Top >= 20 from text view Bottom
- constrain holder view Height to Frame Layout Guide Height (less some Top and Bottom "padding")
- give that Height constraint `Priority: 250 (Default Low)`

Here's how it looks:

[image]

and here's the modified Storyboard source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="End-pl-wnP">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="GaN-aS-ajy">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="End-pl-wnP" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8Qt-g9-qT2">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eZS-Cx-qYs" userLabel="TealScrollView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="335" height="288"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TZH-n0-mbL" userLabel="OrangeHolderView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="12" width="311" height="264"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" scrollEnabled="NO" text="This is the text view." textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7Se-XO-OPS" userLabel="YellowTextView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="311" height="45"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                            </textView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Some View" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2Mx-yX-VZg" userLabel="GreenSomeView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="35.5" y="204" width="240" height="60"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45009386540000001" green="0.98132258650000004" blue="0.4743030667" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="240" id="AqV-is-i0i"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="fff-dn-2i5"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="30"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemOrangeColor"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="7Se-XO-OPS" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="TZH-n0-mbL" secondAttribute="leading" id="2Qh-gf-Aqd"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="7Se-XO-OPS" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="TZH-n0-mbL" secondAttribute="top" id="34Q-R4-aJ7"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="2Mx-yX-VZg" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="7Se-XO-OPS" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Leg-dA-7qH"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="2Mx-yX-VZg" secondAttribute="bottom" id="RxT-uL-vKL"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="7Se-XO-OPS" secondAttribute="trailing" id="UFn-D6-4fs"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="2Mx-yX-VZg" firstAttribute="top" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="7Se-XO-OPS" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="Vfv-7A-o9l"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemTealColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="TZH-n0-mbL" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="QZA-CN-WnC" secondAttribute="width" constant="-24" id="F0n-tQ-VZs"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="TZH-n0-mbL" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="eBA-LY-1GE" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-12" id="Qzd-kt-eRV"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="288" id="U0g-vv-Ze5"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="TZH-n0-mbL" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="eBA-LY-1GE" secondAttribute="leading" constant="12" id="Xcd-EH-rvM"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="TZH-n0-mbL" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="QZA-CN-WnC" secondAttribute="height" priority="250" constant="-24" id="eWO-d1-VMo"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="TZH-n0-mbL" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="eBA-LY-1GE" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="jg5-71-Hyn"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="TZH-n0-mbL" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="eBA-LY-1GE" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-12" id="yc1-tC-Xsw"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="eBA-LY-1GE"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="QZA-CN-WnC"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="NOq-jz-yuG"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="eZS-Cx-qYs" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="NOq-jz-yuG" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="Oh5-z6-HeB"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="eZS-Cx-qYs" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="NOq-jz-yuG" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="ZeN-Gb-OvE"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NOq-jz-yuG" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="eZS-Cx-qYs" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="bxt-As-NfZ"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="waK-s5-f38" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="341" y="155"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="labelColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemOrangeColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.58431372549019611" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemTealColor">
            <color red="0.35294117647058826" green="0.78431372549019607" blue="0.98039215686274506" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: I know this. But as I said, what I want is to have the bottom view at the bottom, not just below the text view. If the view doesn't need scroll it will be anchored to be bottom and when the top view grows then it will be like in the images.

Comment: @DanielIllescas - for future reference, you'll get better answers if you provide clear, complete details about what you're trying to do. See the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: I provided 3 screenshots.